# Android sunshine app(udacity) blank listview

Tags: android, listview

I had successfully implemented the android sunshine app for weather forecast. It was working fine.

I made some updates through updater application and my current version is: `6.7.1.0(KHJMICH)` and OS is `4.4.4KTU84P` and my phone is redmii 2.

Now a problem is coming and I have completely no idea how this happened. Whenever I run my app, a blank listview appears.

So basically I fetch weather forecast in json format using http query sent to openweathermap and then populate the listview.

**I have made no modifications in my source code,it is deto same. This is what is confusing me the most**

Here is the code that populates the listview.

```
package com.example.hp.weather_app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by hp on 20-06-2015.
 */

public  class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    static ArrayAdapter<String> weather_adapter;
    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
        weather_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, x);
        final ListView listview = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);
        listview.setAdapter(weather_adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,View view,int i,long l)
            {
                String msg=(String)listview.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Intent it=new Intent(getActivity(),Detail_Activity.class).putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,msg);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        });
        return rootview;
    }
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecast_fragment, menu);
    }
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        updateweather();
    }
    private void updateweather()
    {
        FetchWeatherTask w=new FetchWeatherTask(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
                getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
        w.execute(location);
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_refresh) {
            FetchWeatherTask w=new FetchWeatherTask(getActivity());
            SharedPreferences prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
                    getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
            w.execute(location);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String ,Context,String []>
{private Context mContext;
    public FetchWeatherTask(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected String [] doInBackground(String []params)
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String forecastJsonStr = null;
        String format="json";
        String units="metric";
        int numDays=7;
        try {
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM="q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM="mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM="units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM="cnt";
            Uri builtUri=Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM,format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM,units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM,Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();
            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr,numDays);
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null) {
            MainActivityFragment.weather_adapter.clear();
            for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
                MainActivityFragment.weather_adapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
        }
    }
    private String getReadableDateString(long time){
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException
    {
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";
        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);
        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);
        dayTime = new Time();
        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);
            long dateTime;
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);
            String HL=formatHighLows(high,low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " +HL;
        }
        return resultStrs;
    }
    public String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        MainActivityFragment obj=new MainActivityFragment();

        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String unitType=sharedPrefs.getString(mContext.getString(R.string.pref_units_key),mContext.getString(R.string.pref_units_metric));
        if(unitType.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.pref_units_imperial)))
        {
            high=(high*1.8)+32;
            low=(low*1.8)+32;
        }
        else if(!unitType.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.pref_units_metric)))
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"invalid unit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);
        String str= roundedHigh+"/"+roundedLow;
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **openweathermap** api now requires an API key. This changed last week. If you have run your app recently, you will more likely see an error in the log:

java.io.FileNotFoundException:http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q= ...

If you caught this exception, such that it doesn't get logged, you could end up with a blank listview because there are no values to populate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Also Could you show me how could I get a key?

Comment: Here's the link [link](http://openweathermap.org/appid). You can register for free and copy the key from the page that results from your registration.

Answer (score 0):

Do notifyDataSetChanged() on array adapter after in onPostExecute() method after for loop.

```
        if (result != null) {
            MainActivityFragment.weather_adapter.clear();
            for(String dayForecastStr : result) {
                MainActivityFragment.weather_adapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
            //also print size of result using logcat to check.                 
            //Do notifydata set change here.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue. What worked for me is appending the key to the Uri immediately following the base URL. Therefore it should look similar to the following where key is equal to the API key given on the openweathermap.org website and "KEY_PARAM" is equal to "APPID".

```
final String FORECAST_BASE_URL ="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
final String KEY_PARAM = "APPID";

        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(KEY_PARAM, key)
                .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                .build();
```